# Add an element at the end of a vector

Tags: perl

I would like to add at the end of a vector that presents already a number of elements the numbers "1" or "0". Let's say that I have 2D vectors with different lenghts like

```
vector[0][0] = 1
vector[0][1] = 3
vector[1][0] = 2
vector[1][1] = 4
vector[1][2] = 5
```

I would like to add at the end of each vector the numbers 1 or 0 (based on an if command); the output sould be:

```
vector[0][0] = 1
vector[0][1] = 3
vector[0][2] = 1
vector[1][0] = 2
vector[1][1] = 4
vector[1][2] = 5
vector[1][3] = 0
```

in which the new elements added are `vector[0][2] = 1` and `vector[1][3]=0`.

I thought of somenthing like:

```
for my $i (0..$#vector) {
    for my $j (0..$#{ $vector[$i] }) {
    if($prob_friendship > (my $random_number=rand()) ) {
        push  @{ $vector[$i][$j] }, 1;
    }
    else {
         push  @{ $vector[$i][$j] }, 0;
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me the error `Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at distribuzione2.pl line 42, <STDIN> line 5.`

Any help?

---

The `$prob_friendship` value is given in input by keyborad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the nested loop, you only need to iterate over the first array index.

You can just iterate using `$i` as you are now and then use `push @{$vector[$i]}, ...`

Alternatively, if you don't actually need to know the array index (and with props to @TLP's answer) you can iterate directly over the individual references stored in the first dimension of `@vector` and do the whole thing in three lines:

```
for my $ref (@vector) {
    push @$ref, ($prob_friendship > rand()) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend `push @{ $vector[$i] }, ...;` even after 5.14 since `push $vector[$i], ...;` is "highly experimental" because it only works with some arrays.

Comment: @ikegami should be OK on a plain unblessed array, but I've gone back to the original syntax as you advise.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the array refs as they are:

```
for my $aref (@vector) {      # will iterate over array refs
    if ($prob > rand()) {
        push @$aref, 1;       # dereferencing the aref
    } else {
        push @$aref, 0;
    }
}
```